# Error in Creating Certificates for EAP in Freeradius

Tags: radius, freeradius

I'm working on creating certificate for **eap-tls** so i can add this certificate to 
mobile and then mobile can access the access point without using username or password

I follow the documentation on **README** in **radiusd/certs**

So i run `make ca.pem` to create Root Certificate , and run `make server.pem` to create Server Certificate

Then run `radiusd -X` but I have this error:

```
Failed reading private key file /etc/raddb/certs/server.pem:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
rlm_eap_tls: Failed initializing SSL context
rlm_eap (EAP): Failed to initialise rlm_eap_tls
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found where is the problem after 3 days of searching

In file **mods-enable/eap**

I have to set the password for `private_key_password = radius`

To be like the password in file **server.cnf**

```
[ req ]
prompt          = no
distinguished_name  = server
default_bits        = 2048
input_password      = radius
output_password     = radius
```

Answer (score 12):

I have this issue when I install  freeradius to fedora 29

I solve it by

```
  
cd  /etc/raddb/certs
./bootstrap
```